# Hide all columns not in CSV string

Tags: excel, vba

I have a comma separated string of letters that correspond to columns I would like to have visible. All other columns should be hidden.

```
sub showOnly()
  Dim displayColumns As String
  Dim displayRange As Range

  displayColumns = "B,C,G,A,C"
  'convert displayColumns to displayRange

  cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
  displayRange.Hidden = False
end sub
```

Edge cases: string may have duplicates and may not be a consecutive range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this method:

```
Sub showOnly()
  Dim displayColumns As String: displayColumns = "B,C,G,A,C"
  Sheet2.UsedRange.Columns.Hidden = True

  Dim ar, col
  ar = Split(displayColumns, ",")
  For Each col In ar
    Sheet2.Columns(col).Hidden = False
  Next

End Sub
```

p.s: no problem with duplicates or non consecutive or discontinuous columns.